# I need some clarification about cloning Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain-fork

I would like, just for learning purpose how to create a new crypto by cloning the Ethereum.

I know how to make a clone of BTC and LTC, basically with that chains is enough modify some strings (such as name and other params) and compile a new wallet that generates a new blockchain.

I would like to do the same with Ethereum, but I'm not sure of what I've understand.
I've read this article:

https://medium.facilelogin.com/build-your-own-blockchain-b8eaeea2f891

So what I need is the “geth” program and the json genesis file, then this is enough to build the blockchain, right?

If yes (and so now I have my own crypto) the step that is not clear for me is: after create genesis block how can I start mining my own crypto (how can I pick a unique network id?)? Where I set the maxium amount of cloned-eth? Is a really new crypto? Can I build a UI for my wallet in any language (maybe Java)? Are there some guide to do that?

Sorry for so many questions, I hope that someone could point me the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Hi there. To get started, you'll probably need a combination of this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/how-to-set-up-a-private-network-and-connect-peers-in-geth and this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/what-does-each-genesis-json-parameter-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: Thank you, your links clarify some situations, but I still have some doubts,first of all I can't see anywhere the maximum amount of cloned-eth, then as I understand any software that interact with geth console could be a UI for my wallets right?

Comment: By reading your requirements I have reached a point that you want your own public blockchain like ethereum!I have to clear you that the article you shared teaches us to create own private blockchain by using geth! By using geth we create our own private blockchain but ethereum is not private blockchain so to clone ethereum you should explore the code of ethereum because ethereum is open source project!
The article you are studying is a seperate thing! And we use geth for private blockchain during development! Hope so this will help you to understand geth and ethereum differences

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you need is a genesis file. It is a jason file that is used to initialize the ethereum network. If you want to clone the ethereum blockchain, you must first get the exact genesis file of the ethereum blockchain. Once you get the genesis file, you have to initialize it using [geth commands](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum).

After you initialize the genesis file, you should now connect to the ethereum network. You can connect to the network if you connect to one of the peers in the network. To connect to peers you should follow [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18291/how-do-i-connect-two-peers-on-different-machines-in-a-private-network).

Once you connect to the peer, the whole ethereum blockchain should now clone to your local directory

Comment: With clone I mean create a new crypto by cloning ethereum